# static method and thread safety

Tags: java

Is the following code threadsafe ?

```
    public static Entity getInstance(){
//the constructor below is a default one.
     return new Entity();
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the constructor itself is thread-safe, that's fine.

It would be very unusual for a constructor *not* to be thread-safe, but possible... even if it's calling the default auto-generated constructor for `Entity`, the base constructor *may* not be thread-safe. I'm not saying it's likely, just possible :)

Basically there's no magic thread-safety applied to static methods *or* instance methods *or* constructors. They can all be called on multiple threads concurrently unless synchronization is applied. If they don't fetch or change any shared data, they will generally be safe - if they *do* access shared data, you need to be more careful. (If the shared data is immutable or only read, that's generally okay - but if one of the threads will be mutating it, you need to be really careful.)

Only static initializers (initialization expressions for static variables and `static { ... }` blocks directly within a class) have special treatment - the VM makes sure they're executed once and only once, blocking other threads which are waiting for the type to be initialized.

Comment: Can you define, what do you mean by `shared data`? What I understand that it would be some static fields of `Enity` class!

Comment: @Akshat: I mean any data that's accessed and modified by multiple threads.

Comment: Ok, suppose in this example, if the constructor initializes some final non-primitive fields & nothing else, does the `getInstance()` method need to be synchronized for thread-safety?

Comment: @Akshat: No, in that case it's okay. It's really if there's mutable data that there's a problem. Will update the answer.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the details of the Entity constructor.  If the Entity constructor modifies shared data, then it is not.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably thread safe, but what's the point? If you're just using a factory method to redirect to the default constructor then why not use the constructor in the first place? So the question is: what are you trying to achieve? The name `getInstance()` suggests a singleton (at least that's common practice), but you clearly don't have a singleton there. If you do want a singleton, use a static inner holder class like this:

```
    public class Singleton {

        private Singleton() {
        }

        public static Singleton getInstance() {
            return InstanceHolder.INSTANCE;
        }

        private static final class InstanceHolder {

            public static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

        }
    }
```

but if you don't, why bother with such a factory method, as you're not adding any value (method name semantics, object pooling, synchronization etc) through it

Answer (score 1):

Thread safety is about access to shared data between different threads. The code in your example doesn't access shared data by itself, but whether it's thread-safe depends on whether the constructor accesses data that could be shared between different threads.

There are a lot of subtle and hard issues to deal with with regard to concurrent programming. If you want to learn about thread safety and concurrent programming in Java, then I highly recommend the book [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) by Brian Goetz.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple threads could call this method and each one will get an unique instance of 'Entity'. So this method 'per se' is thread safe. But if there is code in the constructor or in one of the super constructors that is not thread safe you might have a safety problem anyhow.